# When loging in I get Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

Sorry this is my first attempt at doing backend, it's probably a silly question. I have an index.js like so:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const userRoute = require('./routes/user')
const authRoute = require('./routes/auth')

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

dotenv.config()

mongoose
    .connect(process.env.MONGO_URL)
    .then(() => console.log('db connection succesful'))
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
    })

app.use(express.json())
app.use('/api/auth', authRoute)
app.use('/api/users', userRoute)

app.listen(PORT, () =>{
    console.log(`backend server is running! on ${PORT}`)
})
```

My auth.js looks like:

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const User = require("../models/User");
const CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");

//REGISTER
router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  const newUser = new User({
    username: req.body.username,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
  });

  try {
    const savedUser = await newUser.save();
    res.status(201).json(savedUser);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});

//LOGIN

router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    try{
        const user = await User.findOne({ username: req.body.username });

        !user && res.status(401).json("Wrong User Name");

        password = user.password

        password !== req.body.password && res.status(401).json("Wrong credentials!");

        res.status(200).json(user)

    } catch(err) {
        res.status(500).json(err);
    }

});

module.exports = router;
```

And not sure if this is relevant but my User.js like so:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    isAdmin: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

I am sending a JSON object to my register route:

{
"username": "test",
"email": "100@gmail.com",
"password": 123456
}

Which works. I get the following response in the body when posting to http://localhost:5000/api/auth/register:

```
{
    "username": "test",
    "email": "100@gmail.com",
    "password": "123456",
    "isAdmin": false,
    "_id": "62fd49a6baa5717b67a885df",
    "createdAt": "2022-08-17T20:03:50.776Z",
    "updatedAt": "2022-08-17T20:03:50.776Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

But then when I try post an object to my login (http://localhost:5000/api/auth/login):

```
{
    "username": "test",
    "password": "123456"
}
```

I get the following error:

```
~/code/IaaS/app$ npm start

> app@0.1.0 start
> nodemon index.js

[nodemon] 2.0.19
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
backend server is running! on 5000
db connection succesful
node:internal/errors:465
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:372:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:576:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/home/a7dc/code/IaaS/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:794:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/home/a7dc/code/IaaS/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:174:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (/home/a7dc/code/IaaS/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:278:15)
    at /home/a7dc/code/IaaS/app/routes/auth.js:37:25
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you to Ariel for their answer. I have updated the code to the following:

```
//LOGIN

router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    try{
        const user = await User.findOne({ username: req.body.username });

        !user && res.status(401).json("Wrong User Name");
 
        password = user.password

        password !== req.body.password && res.status(401).json("Wrong credentials!");

        
        if (password !== req.body.password) {
            return res.status(401).json("Wrong credentials!");
         } else {
            return res.status(200).json(user)
         }

    } catch(err) {
        console.log('error')
        return res.status(500).json(err);
    }

});

module.exports = router;
```

Which gives the error:

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
backend server is running! on 5000
db connection succesful
error
node:internal/errors:465
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:372:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:576:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/home/a7dc/code/IaaS/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:794:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/home/a7dc/code/IaaS/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:174:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (/home/a7dc/code/IaaS/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:278:15)
    at /home/a7dc/code/IaaS/app/routes/auth.js:42:32
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: Say you try to login with no username and no password, won't your code try to send a 401, then another 401, then a 200?  That would likely throw the headers already sent error.  Try putting returns after you throw 401.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are sending a response twice (the program is not stopping when you send a response). Here you are sending a response with status 401 and then a response with status 200.

```
        password !== req.body.password && res.status(401).json("Wrong credentials!");

    res.status(200).json(user)
```

Probably, you want to send 401 if the password is different and 200 otherwise

```
            if (password !== req.body.password) {
               res.status(401).json("Wrong credentials!");
            } else {
               res.status(200).json(user)
            }
```

Or maybe, just "return" when the response is sent. Example:

```
return res.status(XXX).json({ something: "something})
```

"Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client" means that one response is already sent so you can't set the headers again.

Comment: Thank you Ariel, I have updated the OP with the changes you suggested and a new error. Maybe I'm doing it wrong?

Comment: Check other places in your code that are returning a response res.XXXXX. Basically, when you use res.json({}) you are sending a response to the client and the flow of your program must end there